# Using WebSockets with EM and IRC to Send "Connection Successful" Message

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I'm attempting to write an IRC client using WebSockets. The IRC client I found on GitHub uses EventMachine, but I'm trying to use WebSockets as well to notify any connected clients when they're connected. However, I don't think I'm quite understanding EventMachine, because although the client successfully connects and joins the IRC channel, the `puts 'Connected...'` nor the subsequent line gets executed.

I assume this is because of a fundamental misunderstanding of EventMachine on my behalf.

```
EM.run {

  EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080) do |websocket|

    websocket.onopen {

      irc = Net::YAIL.new(
          :address    => 'irc.my-example-server.net',
          :port       => 6667,
          :username   => 'MyExample',
          :realname   => 'My Example Bot',
          :nicknames  => ['MyExample1', 'MyExample2', 'MyExample3']
      )

      irc.on_welcome proc { |event|
        irc.join('#ExampleChannel')
        EM.next_tick {
          puts 'Connected...'
          websocket.send({ :message => 'Connected' })
        }
      }

      irc.start_listening!
    }

  end
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think I've answered my own question after a night of research. Essentially it has nothing to do with my misunderstanding of EventMachine. It's just the IRC client I was attempting to use was simply an infinite loop, and therefore nothing else could interrupt it. After researching for a further couple of hours for an EventMachine compatible IRC client, I came across Ponder: https://github.com/tbuehlmann/ponder so now hopefully I can continue creating my application!

Shameless plug: https://github.com/Wildhoney/Banter.js

Comment: I'm the author of Ponder, so I'll just leave you a note about the project not being maintained anymore. So, stay alert. :)